# Building an AtMega328p from Transistors

Tags: assembly

I'm a little new to circuitry, and the Arduino in itself!

From what I know, I think that it might be possible to actually build one (the processor itself, of course) from transistors. This isn't a practical question, of course, but it would be an excellent learning opportunity.

Would it be actually possible to go through with such a project (Even without EEPROM)?

If so, how would it be completed?

Thank you!

Comment: Transistors - :). Gates - yes but just too much work. FPGA - yes. Check estimated number of transistors https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.embedded/14362-1.php

Comment: Start easy and e.g. build a 4-bit adder. The go for a 4-bit ALU. I.e. start small, and keep extending it.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you take a look at Ben Eater's video series about building an 8-bit computer on breadboards: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU 
He doesn't build it from transistors, and it isn't an AVR CPU, but he explains in detail the function of each IC he uses for this project, including possible circuits to duplicate the IC's functionality with transistors. With this approach he keeps the whole thing relatively compact, and still manages to visualise every detail of the CPU's inner workings using plenty of LEDs and a single-step clock mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible - after all, the Arduino is essentially just a bunch of incredibly tiny transistors. Early computers, before ICs were invented, were built from transistors. Before that it was valves. Before that it was relays. All just, at the end of the day, switches.

Would it be a practical project? Not really, although someone has done it (not for the AVR CPU, but the concept is the same): http://www.megaprocessor.com/

How would you start? Well, first off you'd create the basic building blocks of a CPU, which is logic gates. There are two basic ones that can be combined together to make any other gate: the NAND gate and the NOR gate. You'd pick one of those and put lots of them together to make the basic sections of the CPU. Then those blocks connect together to form the CPU. More logic gates go together to make the IO functionality, memory, interfaces, etc.

Basically:

- Transistors combine to make NAND gates (or NOR gates if you prefer that form)
- NAND (or NOR) gates combine to make complex gates.
- Complex gates combine to make logic functions
- Logic functions combine to make logic blocks (like the ALU)
- Logic blocks combine to make the CPU

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This is really helpful! This looks _really, really_ hard, but I still might try it... Thank you!

Comment: If I really were doing this by hand, I would not make complex gates out of NANDs (nor NORs), as it would be more efficient to make them directly out of transistors. As an example, NOT(A AND B OR C) can be made with 6 transistors in CMOS (and only 3 in NMOS or PMOS). Many more transistors would be needed if one would be restricted to use only universal gates.

Comment: @EdgarBonet That's the same as what you end up with after optimization of your discrete gate circuits.

Comment: But then, going through an all-NAND design seems like useless extra work.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Which is why it's an essential step in the project. The whole project is useless extra work. And if you have to ask the question that the OP asked then you obviously have no understanding of logic gates etc so starting simple with NAND is a basic requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you could build an ATmega328P out of discrete parts: you
would need floating-gate transistors for implementing the flash, and
these do not seem to be available as discretes.

If you forgo the flash (or replace it with RAM or ROM), then it should
in principle be possible. This processor, however, is probably not a
good choice for such a project. From [the discussion](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showthread/comp.arch.embedded/14362-1.php) linked to by
Mikael Patel, it seems you would need something like 80 K
transistors for the core alone, and much more if you include the RAM and
the peripherals. It would be a daunting task to assemble all this by
hand. For comparison, the [Megaprocessor](http://www.megaprocessor.com/)<sup>1</sup> as about
42 K transistors total (core + RAM + LED drivers).

If you want to pursue such a project, I recommend you target a simpler
CPU. The [MOS 6502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) may be a good choice. This CPU, which was very
popular in the late 70s and early 80s, has “only” 3,510 transistors and
is well documented. See for example the resources at [visual6502.org](http://www.visual6502.org/).
They have an amazing [online transistor-level simulator](http://www.visual6502.org/JSSim/) built from
the actual layout of the chip.

<sup>1</sup>Thanks Majenko for the link

Answer (score 2):

The ATmega128 have 800000 transistors. (+-200000 transistors)
So If you want to take some transistors and breadboards and build an ATmega128p
first count the money for transistors (if 1 transistor costs 0.01€ then 800000 x 0.01 = 8000€ and the breadboards is much more expensive than transistors!)

Answer (score 2):

Try to build out the entire thing inside a simulator instead of buying 10s of thousands of transistors and several other components....less messy and gets the job done at almost no expense

Comment: Please suggest a few simulators in your answer, otherwise it may get flagged as a comment / not an answer.

Comment: There's too many, check out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_electronics_circuit_simulators and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_circuit_simulation and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software

Comment: https://www.electroschematics.com/2249/pcb-design-software/

Comment: Even an entire plant with all equipment and processes running live can be simulated: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_Simulation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotics_simulator

Comment: There's a startup/website called labster that has all sorts of simulators for students. Facebook's metaverse and Nvidia's omniverse will soon incorporate such virtual labs and twin factories.

Answer (score 1):

Why not? Atmel did it.  But if you mean by soldering up discretes...

In the mid 70s the Zilog Z80 had 8,500 transistors; a couple of years later, the Intel 8088 had 29000(source: [Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor_count). Neither of those had on-chip memory. The AtMega 328p has 2K of RAM and 1K of EEPROM on chip, so factor in for those and their drivers. At 20 MHz it will probably be fun 1) keeping signals where they belong; and 2) keeping the wire runs short enough and suitably arranged that capacitance doesn't slow and distort the signals to unusability.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible, you will have to spend a lot of money and a lot of time. I think about thousends of dollars and months of work. Even when accomplished you will have learned more about electronics than about the ATmega328P. In order to accomplish, you will also have to ask Atmel to hand you over the schematics to get the inner working right. I highly doubt they will aggree since it is not Open Hardware.

I highly discourage you to do that. Instead I suggest you start with an Arduino UNO and discover the capabilities and then go a step further and use a bare ATmege328P.

Comment: Although you cannot get the schematic of the real Atmel’s AVR, there are a few AVR clones available at http://opencores.org/

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be actually possible to go through with such a project (Even without EEPROM)?

yes.

> If so, how would it be completed?

the easiest would be to find or write a soft-core for AVR on a fpga. Get the logic blocks for that softcore , and then implement those logic blocks with transistors.

Before you set out actually doing it, however, check if you have enough of space or bank account (for the electric bills).